# Dependency error while installing Kurento under Ubunto v.14.04

Tags: dependencies, kurento

I would like to install Kurento (http://www.kurento.org/documentation) in my linux machine Ubunto 14.04.

I follow the instruction for installation which are:

```
echo "deb http://ubuntu.kurento.org trusty kms6" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kurento.list
```

The output is :

```
deb http://ubuntu.kurento.org trusty kms6
```

and then:

```
wget -O - http://ubuntu.kurento.org/kurento.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

The output is:

```
--2015-11-30 18:55:44--  http://ubuntu.kurento.org/kurento.gpg.key
Resolving ubuntu.kurento.org (ubuntu.kurento.org)... 193.147.51.5
Connecting to ubuntu.kurento.org     (ubuntu.kurento.org)|193.147.51.5|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 1694 (1.7K) [application/pgp-keys]
Saving to: ‘STDOUT’

100%[======================================>] 1,694       --.-K/s   in 0s      

2015-11-30 18:55:44 (234 MB/s) - written to stdout [1694/1694]

OK
```

and then :

```
sudo apt-get update
```

and PART of the output is:

```
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release   
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Sources
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe i386 Packages
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse i386 Packages               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en                
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/main Translation-en_US                 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/multiverse Translation-en_US           
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/restricted Translation-en_US           
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com trusty/universe Translation-en_US             
Reading package lists... Done
```

and finally :

```
sudo apt-get install kurento-media-server-6.0
```

After running the last line of code, I encounter the following dependency errors.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
kurento-media-server-6.0 : Depends: kms-core-6.0 (>= 6.2.0) but it is   not going to be installed
                        Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.41.1) but 2.40.2-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
                        Depends: libgstreamer1.5-0 (>= 1.7.0.1~20151111095734.298.g6d22bfb.trusty) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gstreamer1.5-plugins-base (>= 1.7.0~0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gstreamer1.5-libav (>= 1.7.0~0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gstreamer1.5-plugins-bad (>= 1.7.0~0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gstreamer1.5-plugins-good (>= 1.7.0~0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: gstreamer1.5-plugins-ugly (>= 1.7.0~0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: kms-elements-6.0 (>= 6.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: kms-filters-6.0 (>= 6.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

In your opinion, how could the error be resolved? Thanks

Comment: Could you edit your answer posting the output of those four commands?

Comment: Thank you, I did as you mentioned. Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you try this?  `sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0`
This way we can know why the package cannot be installed and try to resolve dependencies

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your comment. After trying `sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0` the library was installed and it seems `sudo apt-get install kurento-media-server-6.0` did NOT invoke any error. So I could start the server using `sudo service kurento-media-server-6.0 start` . 

Can I know a little bit more about the source of the problem and how it was solved?

Comment: The problem was that kurento is providing version of glib newer than the default in ubuntu 14.04, this can cause problems is you already have libglib2.0 already installed and not updated because during the update is requiring the installation of newer dependencies and `apt-get` complains if you are not installing the library directly or performing an `apt-get dist-upgrade`